# Filtering through grid filter plugin on ExtJS, headerContext.state.boxPlan undefined

Tags: extjs

I am using the built in plugin to add a filter option by adding the following in my grid panel:

```
plugins: 'gridfilters'
```

Now my header menu has an option to filter where i can enter texts, but one problem i see is that when nothing matches, for example enter `z` into the filter box, the entire grid just breaks.. why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Fiddle here: 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11pi

Firebug shows: `TypeError: ownerContext.headerContext.state.boxPlan is undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `layout: 'hbox'` on the grid. You're not controlling how the grid is laid out, leave that to the grid.